# libav Windows static libraries

Tags: visual-c++, ffmpeg, libav

Does anybody know how can I build libav static libraries (.lib) for use them in my projects?

Answer (score 0):

Before compiling LibAV one needs to configure LibAV by 'configure' script. Use '--enable-static' :

./configure --enable-static

The script 'configure' generates make-files according to chosen or default parameters, example of LibAV configuration parameters:

./configure --target-os=mingw32 --arch=x86 --enable-shared **--enable-static** --enable-dxva2 --disable-encoders --enable-hwaccel=dxva2 --extra-cflags=-O3 --enable-pthreads